# JavaFX Checkboard

Tags: java, javafx

For some reason this program wont work and I still cannot see the problem. This is a javaFX problem that wants me to use CSS and TextFields as the checkboard. But everytime I put it in this for loop is doesn't work.

```
public class IjazZ_CH15P5 extends Application
{
  @Override
  public void start(Stage stage)
  {
    GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();

    int n = 5; // The column/row number that can be changed

    TextField bSquare = new TextField();
    TextField wSquare = new TextField();

    bSquare.setEditable(false);
    wSquare.setEditable(false);

    bSquare.setStyle("-fx-background-color: black;");
    wSquare.setStyle("-fx-background-color: white;");

    for (int col = 0; col > n; col++)
    {
     for(int row = 0; row > n; row++)
     {
       if ((row%2) == (col%2))
       {
         gridPane.add(bSquare,col,row);
       }
       else
       {
         gridPane.add(wSquare,col,row);
       }
     }
    }

    stage.setScene(new Scene(gridPane)); 
    stage.setTitle("Checkboard"); 
    stage.show();
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please be more specific than "doesn't work"?

Comment: It suppose to make a black and white checkboard. And when I do gridPane.add(bSquare,0,0) it will add the black square. But when I run it through this for loop it wont add anything.

Comment: That is the strangest class name I've seen in a while.

Comment: It's homework lmfao. He makes us write it like that. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. TBH I think it's just netbeans not working or something.

Comment: bSquare.setStyle("-fx-background-color: black;"); << there is compiler error here, gridPane.add(bSquare,col,row); < another error here

Comment: @Rico I get no compiler errors.

Comment: Hint (for the first of multiple issues): are the conditions in your `for` loops `true` or `false` on the first iteration of the loop?

Comment: But there is no stack trace problem. I've compiled it and ran it with no problems. It's just that nothing shows up.

Comment: Well, there will be when you fix your loops... :)

Comment: Ahh I see it. For some reason my textbook doesn't explain this to us in detail. Thanks for the help.

Comment: idk, i had netbeans open n i copy pasted the code n boooom i got the errors o.O

Comment: error: cannot find symbol
    bSquare.setStyle("-fx-background-color: black;");
  symbol:   method setStyle(String)
  location: variable bSquare of type TextField

Comment: @Rico you probably imported the wrong classes. (Specifically the wrong `TextField`.)

Comment: what did u guys import? import java.awt.TextField;
import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

Comment: @Rico Exactly... `java.awt.TextField`???

Comment: ioException is not needed it, was for my own app

Comment: ok. now its compiling, hold on,  i will check the output now

Comment: Yea for those who are reading this comment the problem was that i messed up the greater than/ less than stament in the for loop. Also you have to create the an instance of the textfield every time you loop. Can't have the same instance of the same TextField in a grid.

Comment: yay,  a blank window !!!!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your `for` loops have the wrong logical operators. They should be less thans (`<`).

Secondly, you cannot add duplicate items into a grid pane, so you will need to create a new instance of the text field every iteration of the loop.

I've tested this and it works:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage)
{
  GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();

  int n = 5; // The column/row number that can be changed

  for (int col = 0; col < n; col++)
  {
   for(int row = 0; row < n; row++)
   {
     if ((row%2) == (col%2))
     {
       TextField bSquare = new TextField();
       bSquare.setEditable(false);
       bSquare.setStyle("-fx-background-color: black;");
       gridPane.add(bSquare,col,row);
     }
     else
     {
       TextField wSquare = new TextField();
       wSquare.setEditable(false);
       wSquare.setStyle("-fx-background-color: white;");
       gridPane.add(wSquare,col,row);
     }
   }
  }

  stage.setScene(new Scene(gridPane)); 
  stage.setTitle("Checkboard"); 
  stage.show();
}
```

Comment: Oh wow thank you thats the most rookie mistake I have ever seen. Geez now i feel like you've done my homework for me.

Comment: No problem. Sometimes the simplest problems are the hardest to see. I suggest you play around with your IDE's debugger if you haven't already. Being able to step through your code one statement at a time is incredibly helpful.

Comment: Yea the teacher told me the class to download it specifically for this problem since dr.java doesn't work withh javaFX elements.

Comment: but text field is so old school, use canvas it will look more sophisticated